# Blank white screen shown when starting an activity from a notification

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, pusher

I'm using Pusher(which depends on Firebase Cloud messaging ) to send notifications to my android app. when app is in the foreground, and i click the received notification in the notification drawer, the `main` activity is launched without any issue.
When i close the app by long pressing the back button, i will still receive the notification but when i click it, a blank white screen opens and app remain stuck on this page. adding logs to my activity `onCreate` show's it's never called on this situation.

I've even tried to set the flags below in my pending intent but they didn't work

```
intent.apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT
        }
```

even adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` on the activity declaration in the manifest file didn't solve the solution.

manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".find.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.TransparentStatus"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateAlwaysHidden"
        />
```

Messaging service

```
class NotificationsMessagingService : MessagingService() {

override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
    Log.e("MessagingService", " NOTIFICATION RECEIVED")
    var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.apply { 
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        }

     sendNotification("You have a new notification",remoteMessage.notification.body, intent)

}

fun sendNotification(title: String, body: String, intent: Intent) {
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
    val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, getString(R.string.notification_title), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

}

Comment: I'm curious to what happens when you add this     `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>`  to your theme. Is the screen black now instead of white?

Comment: @avalerio yes, that will show a white screen for a second and then the black screen. the main issue is that the screens are blank. the main activity is never called

Comment: Please replace `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` with `0` when creating the `PendingIntent` and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, please post the code of `MainActivity.onCreate()`. Also, did you check the logcat when this occurs? Please don't filter the logcat or you might miss something important. You might see the reason why your app is not properly started. I find it hard to believe that `onCreate()` is not called, as that is what would be showing the white screen.

Comment: @DavidWasser check my answer below. i figured out what was happening

Comment: OK. Glad you were able to solve it. Please accept your answer as that may help someone else with  a similar problem, as well as removing the question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is in the background or has been killed, `NotificationsMessagingService` is never called. pusher sends the notification direct to the notification drawer. upon clicking it, one is taken to the app launcher activity which happens to be splash screen activity in my case.

It is from the Splash screen activity's `onCreate` method that i get the notification data from the intent's extra and consume it just as i would do when i receive the notification from `NotificationsMessagingService`

```
class SplashActivity : Activity(){


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   
    if (intent.extras != null) {
        processIntent(intent)
    }
}
```